# XLOOKUP with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a multi-criteria XLookup formula into VBA, but I continually get

> Error 13 Type Mismatch.

A simple XLookup with single criteria works fine, so it must be something to do with the way I am trying to concatenate my requirements.

```
Sub Test1()

    'This works fine
    Range("F18").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Range("F13").Value, Range("C:C"), Range("A:A"))

    'This gives Error 13 Type Mismatch
    Range("H18").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Range("H11").Value & Range("H13").Value, Range("C:C") & Range("D:D"), Range("A:A"))

End Sub
```

The native formula `=XLOOKUP(H11&H13,C:C&D:D,A:A)` works fine in Excel so there must be a way of writing this in VBA.

Comment: Just a sidenote, concatenating values within a lookup or match is rarely a great idea.... what about concatenating `US` and `A` and you lookup this value in a column where you concatenated `U` and `SA`...

Comment: You can't `Range("C:C") & Range("D:D")` in VBA... that's trying to concatenate two arrays.

Comment: Following up on @BigBen's comment - do you wish the result to be `Range("C:D")` in your `Range("C:C") & Range("D:D")` part of the `XLOOKUP` statement?

Comment: Thanks JvdV, that's an interesting short-coming I wasn't aware of, though I would have been ok as the first element is a fixed length string.

Comment: Thanks BigBen & Prebsus. I'm asking it to find the first row that contains the value of H11  in column C and the value of H13 in column D, and for the result to be the value of column A in that row. It works well in native Excel. Microsoft have designed XLookup() so that you can concatenate two ranges, so I'm surprised they haven't incorporated the same logic into the WorksheetFunction.XLookup. I guess I can work around it by getting Excel to perform the function in a hidden area of the sheet and just write some code to retrieve the result.

Comment: @lookalike - `&` within the function isn't going to work the same way in VBA. You could use `Evaluate` probably.

Comment: @BigBen - that worked a treat, thank you.  I wasn't familiar with Evaluate, but `Range("H18").Value = Application.Evaluate("=XLOOKUP(H11&H13,C:C&D:D,A:A)")` did what I wanted.

Comment: If you want to reference another worksheet (not ActiveSheet) method using Evaluate becomes very cumbersome as you would be required to use full qualified range references. Very difficult to "un-hard-code" below example: =XLOOKUP("UK"&"Birmingham",'Data.xlsx'!PopulationTable[Country]&'Data.xlsx'!PopulationTable[City],'Data.xlsx'!PopulationTable[Population])