# Xlookup with multiple criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

I feel like this is something stupidly simple, but I've been Googling and experimenting for a while and seem to be coming up empty handed guess is I'm searching the wrong term/word. Anyway, let me explain.

for Example :

> this code: Run -Time error '13' Type mismatch

```
Dim ws, sh As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
 
Dim Ctr1, Ctr2, Result As Range
 
Set Ctr1 = ws.Range("A2:A100")

Set Ctr2 = ws.Range("B2:B100")

Set Result = ws.Range("C2:C100")
 

With sh 
    .Cells(2, 7).Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup( _
    .Cells(2, 5) & .Cells(2, 6), Ctr1 & Ctr2, Result, 0)
       
End With

 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't tag unrelated languages.

Comment: Sorry, will be careful next time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594077/xlookup-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084665/8422953

Answer (score 1):

Create the XLOOKUP parameters from the range addresses.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim Ctr1, Ctr2, Result As Range
    Set Ctr1 = ws.Range("A2:A100")
    Set Ctr2 = ws.Range("B2:B100")
    Set Result = ws.Range("C2:C100")
    
    '  XLOOKUP parameters
    Dim p(3) As String, i As Long, w As String
    w = "'" & ws.Name & "'!"
    p(1) = w & Ctr1.Address(0, 0) & "&" & _
           w & Ctr2.Address(0, 0)
    p(2) = w & Result.Address(0, 0)
    p(3) = 0
    
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    With sh
        For i = 2 To 2
            p(0) = .Cells(i, 5).Address(0, 0) & "&" & .Cells(i, 6).Address(0, 0)
            .Cells(i, 7).Formula = "=XLOOKUP(" & Join(p, ",") & ")"
        Next
    End With
    
End Sub
```