# VBA xlook multi criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7

Im trying to work this code here, but I'm getting an error "run time error 1004' Method 'Range' of object worksheet failed'

What I'm trying to do is xlookup 2 criteria. But im having a hard time to come up with the right code.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim shData As Worksheet
Dim shLookup As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set shData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set shLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lookup")

lastRow = shLookup.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    shLookup.Range("c" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(shLookup.Range("a", "b" & i).Value, shData.Range("b" & "c"), shData.Range("D"), "-")
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xlookup in via with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361004/xlookup-in-via-with-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Please help me excel masters